Showing percetage of the year in LaTeX
I'm trying to make a contract in LaTeX, where I express the responability of a property the year is signed. To do so, I need to calculate de percentage of the year that has already passed.
I would need to calculate the number of days in this year, the day in which we are, and then make a division, aproaching to 2 decimal digits.
Any idea more simple?
Already explained above

You could use pgfcalendar:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}

\newcounter{julian}
\newcounter{silvester}
\newcounter{newyear}
\newcounter{yeardays}
\newcounter{nowdays}

\makeatletter
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-\month-\day}{\c@julian} 
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-12-31}{\c@silvester} 
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-01-01}{\c@newyear} 
\makeatother

\addtocounter{newyear}{-1}
\setcounter{yeardays}{\thesilvester}
\addtocounter{yeardays}{-\thenewyear}
\setcounter{nowdays}{\thejulian}
\addtocounter{nowdays}{-\thenewyear}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{\value{nowdays}/\value{yeardays}}
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}

\end{document}

